# Add icons in paginate_links()

Tags: pagination

I have added the following in my woocommerce pagination

```
    <?php
           echo paginate_links( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_pagination_args', array(
                    'base'         => $base,
                    'format'       => $format,
                    'add_args'     => false,
                    'current'      => max( 1, $current ),
                    'total'        => $total,
                    'prev_text'    => '&larr;',
                    'next_text'    => '&rarr;',
                    'type'         => 'list',
                    'end_size'     => 3,
                    'mid_size'     => 3,
                    'next_text' => __('>'),
                ) ) );

            ?>
```

The above works and generates the following:

```
<ul class="page-numbers">
    <li><span aria-current="page" class="page-numbers current">1</span></li>
  <li><a class="page-numbers" href="http://127.0.0.1:8090/en/product-category/marble/page/2/">2</a></li>
  <li><a class="page-numbers" href="http://127.0.0.1:8090/en/product-category/marble/page/3/">3</a></li>
  <li><a class="next page-numbers" href="http://127.0.0.1:8090/en/product-category/marble/page/2/">&gt;</a></li>

</ul>
```

I would also like to add the possibility of having another li which would then move to the last page and another to the fitst page.

How can i add the fist and last page link in the pagination which would be very useful especially when there is alot of pagination links.